# Put the data in text file on the list or fame

Tags: r, list, frame

There are some datas(protein ID),for example:P91913 P0DM41 Q93573 P49197.I want to download sequence information in http://www.uniprot.org ,now I can download one,but I want to download many. And every url is different only in ID when I gain the .fasta . Therefore,I want put these ID on a list or frame, then through ID one by one.Now these IDs are in a text file,what should I do if I want to use loooping statements to acess the ID one by one to gain the sequence information of different ID. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need to use the `XML` package at all. I believe my edited answer would do your job.

Comment: I have ran the code that you edited and gain the information that I want to get.But I have many ids in a text file , I want to get all sequence of ids in a text file.Therefore,I guess whether I can deal with the vectors to bulid a set of vectors so that I can gain all sequence information. At the beginning,I pretend to use the list or frame and for looping.But I Can't make it works!What should I do on codesand whether the methods that I say is workable!Thanks!@Ven Yao

Comment: Suppose you had a file that contained all the ids with each line contained one id. Then, you can simply read your file into R using the `readLines` function. x <- readLines("allids.txt"). Then proceed with my answer. You may want to read the manual of readLines and read.table, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help,I have solved my questions!

Comment: I accept your answers that suggested for me and your answers is useful for me!

Comment: I mean you may want to mark my answer below as the right answer to your question. Thx.

Comment: I agree with your answers! I think that your answers solved my question perfectly.Thanks!

Comment: I try the methods that you say,but there are many errors .I use many methods to debug, but it doesn't work.x<-readLines("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\蛋白质ID号.txt"),y <- sapply(x, function(i) {
    url <- paste("http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/", i, ".fasta", sep="")
    return(readLines(url))
}) 
writeLines(unlist(y), "E:\\qq.txt")  what should I do? Thx.@Ven Yao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x <- c("P91913", "P0DM41", "Q93573", "P49197")
y <- sapply(x, function(i) {
    url <- paste("http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/", i, ".fasta", sep="")
    return(readLines(url))
})

writeLines(unlist(y), "E:\\qq.txt")
```